# How can I make all properties virtual on entities generated by EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t4

Normally on EF 6 when the entities are generated they put the properties in the style 'public type column'. Is there a way to increase a virtual in this properties like 'public virtual type column'?

I'm actually using the EF model design to generate the entities and this model have a file with extension .tt that's look like is the code to generate the entities class, but is very confusing.

Comment: Do you want all the properties generated to be virtual, or do you want some of them to be virtual?  If you want them all, you could modify the T4 template (that TT file) to do it.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_Template_Transformation_Toolkit and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2019.  You might also want to look at the Reverse Poco tool (https://www.reversepoco.co.uk/)

Comment: Please clarify what "increase a virtual" means--I don't think that is a generally recognised term.

Comment: @Flydog57 I want all properties generated to be virtual

Comment: I'm not a T4 expert so I can't help.  You probably want to tag your question with `t4` to get the right folks helping you.  I'm curious, though, why do you want to make all your properties virtual?

Comment: @Flydog57 I'm making inheritance with the entities class and sometimes I have to override this properties. And I think that I found the string.Format that make the properties in cs file. I will probably answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the method that make the properties in .cs file in the T4 template (.tt file in EF Model Design).

```
public string Property(EdmProperty edmProperty)
{
    return string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        "{0} virtual {1} {2} {{ {3}get; {4}set; }}",
        Accessibility.ForProperty(edmProperty),
        _typeMapper.GetTypeName(edmProperty.TypeUsage),
        _code.Escape(edmProperty),
        _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForGetter(edmProperty)),
        _code.SpaceAfter(Accessibility.ForSetter(edmProperty)));
}
```

I just added a 'virtual' in the string format.

Comment: On a side note, the word you are looking for is "add" not increase.